# How to pass on data that are fetched from Firestore as props to a component

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, use-effect

I am fetching data from Cloud Firestore with this code

```
const [profile, setProfile] = useState({});
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchDoc = async() => {
    const response = await db.collection("users").doc(id).get();
    const data = response.data();
    setProfile({...data});
  }
  fetchDoc();
}, []);
```

This saves an object to the state that looks like this

```
{
  name: 'sample name',
  tertiary: {
    name: ['sample 1', 'sample 2', ...]
  },
  ...
}
```

The first time the page mounts, `console.log(profile)` returns an empty object. But then, as from what I know, useEffect triggers after this mounting, and fetches the data. Afterwards, `console.log(profile)` now returns the object fetched.

Now, for some reason, when I pass `profile.tertiary.name` as props to a component, I get an error that says it is `undefined`. This happens every time the page first mounts, and useEffect doesn't do anything afterwards.

```
<CustomBioList education={profile.tertiary.name} />
```

In the `<CustomBioList />` component, I'm simpy trying to `console.log(props)` to check whether it gets the data. Am I fetching the data in a wrong way? I don't grasp the full concept of useEffect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`profile.tertiary` is initially `undefined`, so trying to access `profile.tertiary.name` will throw an error.

You could add a check by replacing `<CustomBioList education={profile.tertiary.name} />` with `(profile.tertiary ? <CustomBioList education={profile.tertiary.name} /> : <span>Loading...</span>` or something similar.

Comment: Is there a way I could get the data immediately, and then render the page?

Comment: You would have to wait to obtain the data (the database does not return immediately, hence `await` is required). If you want nothing to be rendered before the data is obtained, you could simply return a blank page first if `profile.tertiary` is `undefined`.

Comment: I assumed when the `useEffect` triggers, it would cause a re-render of the DOM, but the error seems to stop it? Is it not the case?

Comment: It would cause a re-render when the state is modified (so after the database call is completed, not necessarily when `useEffect` is called). Only after that does React try to re-render and is unable to do so because of the `undefined` error.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever we pass data to props which is not defined, as in your case, the data (`profile`) initially is `{}` and hence when the component mounts the first time it passes the prop as `profile.tertiary.name` which should be `undefined` because the useEffect is yet yo run.

Better way would be something like this:

```js
<CustomBioList education={profile && profile.tertiary && profile.tertiary.name} />
```

which is nothing but, making sure that `profile` has an object `tertiary`.

---

Other solution could be, of rendering the component only if it having some value, something like this:

```js
(!!profile && !!profile.tertiary && <CustomBioList education={profile.tertiary.name} />)
```